# Woocommerce - update_order_review become 502 after add_discount programmatically

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, coupon

I need some help. I want to implement, add existing coupon to cart when some conditions are fulfilled. I've got nothing wrong with the condition. But, when the function are going to add discount to coupon, the `wc-ajax=update_order_review` become 502.

However, if I do another things like changing address or something that can re-run `update_order_review`, it become 200. `update_order_review` successfully running and coupon is added to cart.

This is my function code so far, and I've copied some code from stackoverflow forum too

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'discount_based_on_weight_threshold');
function discount_based_on_weight_threshold( $cart ) {
    if (  ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Your settings
    $coupon_code      = 'freeongkir8krpx'; // Coupon code

    // Initializing variables
    $applied_coupons  = $cart->get_applied_coupons();
    $coupon_code      = sanitize_text_field( $coupon_code );
    $methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $method = isset( $methods[ 0 ] ) ? $methods[ 0 ] : false;
    $kupon = new WC_Coupon('freeongkir10k');
    
    if($method !== 'jne_shipping_test'){
        if($cart->get_subtotal() <= $kupon->get_minimum_amount()){
            $user = wp_get_current_user();
                error_log( 'CHECK USER ROLES');
                error_log( print_r($user->roles, TRUE) );
                if(in_array( 'administrator', (array) $user->roles )){
                    // Applying coupon
                    if( ! in_array($coupon_code, $applied_coupons)  ){
                        $cart->add_discount( $coupon_code );
                        wc_clear_notices();
                    }
                }
        } else {
            if( in_array($coupon_code, $applied_coupons) ){
                $cart->remove_coupon( $coupon_code );
            }   
        }
    } else {
        if( in_array($coupon_code, $applied_coupons) ){
            $cart->remove_coupon( $coupon_code );
        }
    }
}
```

When I disable `$cart->add_discount( $coupon_code );`, it running successfully, so I pretty sure that adding discount is the trigger.

And the flow that I used is

1. Go to checkout, conditions fulfilled, `add_discount` error, another function re-run `update_order_review`, coupon applied.
2. Change shipping methods, conditions not fulfilled, applied coupon is deleted
3. Change shipping methods, conditions fulfilled, `add_discount` error, `update_order_review` become 502, no other function re-run `update_order_review`, infinite loading in checkout order review

So any wrong code or flow do I have? or there are any ways to trick the error since it will applied the code if the `update_order_review` are re-run

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any helpful information in your browser console or the wp error log?

If I remember right 502 on AJAX request means the code fails to give you a valid response.
Hm, I don't yet have a helpful answer.

I refactored your code a bit to improve readability.
This should do exactly what your code does.

`add_discount()` has been renamed `apply_coupon()` - maybe try that.

```
<?php
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'discount_based_on_weight_threshold');
function discount_based_on_weight_threshold( $cart ) {
    if (  ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Your settings
    $coupon_code      = 'freeongkir8krpx'; // Coupon code

    // Initializing variables
    $applied_coupons = $cart->get_applied_coupons();
    $coupon_code     = sanitize_text_field( $coupon_code );
    $methods         = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $method          = isset( $methods[ 0 ] ) ? $methods[ 0 ] : false;
    $kupon           = new WC_Coupon('freeongkir10k');

    // remove code if already applied
    if( in_array($coupon_code, $applied_coupons) ){
       $cart->remove_coupon( $coupon_code );
    }
    
    if(
        $method !== 'jne_shipping_test') &&
        $cart->get_subtotal() <= $kupon->get_minimum_amount()
    ){
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        error_log( 'CHECK USER ROLES');
        error_log( print_r($user->roles, TRUE) );
        if( in_array( 'administrator', (array) $user->roles ) ){
            // Applying coupon
            $cart->apply_coupon( $coupon_code );
            wc_clear_notices();
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. 

I've look at the wp error, but it show nothing except my `error_log` debugging code. And in browser console, I only have `POST https://www.[mypage].com/?wc-ajax=update_order_review 502 (Bad Gateway)`

I've already change add_discount to apply_coupon, but it didn't give any changes